Can you determine $\text{tr}(J_i J_j)$ without specifying representation
As my question in the title states, if I have $J$ to be the generators of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ together with the Lie bracket $[J_i,J_j] = \epsilon_{ijk} J_k$, is it possible then to deduce
$$\text{tr}(J_i J_j)$$
without specifying a representation?
I found an article online on this https://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph218/sunid17.pdf
However, they seem to assume $\text{tr}(J_iJ_j) = 1/2 \delta_{ij}$ for the defining representation before they proceed to determine an epxression for $
$$\text{tr}(J_i J_j)$ for any $n$ which is the opposite of what I am trying to look for.

So is the question simply asking about how to calculate the trace for the defining representation? It is a normalization convention, meaning it can be multiplied by any number you want and the theory will still work out.

@Trebor The question is whether it is possible to compute it without specifying the representation. Sorry if I was unclear.

It is different for each representation, so do you want a formula that works for all the representations?

Note that in the note $\mathfrak{su}(N)$ is the space of traceless Hermitian $N\times N$ matrices
$$ \mathfrak{su}(N) = \{ A \in GL(N, \mathbb C) : \operatorname{tr}(A) =0, \ A = A^*\}.$$
Hence for each $A, B\in \mathfrak {su}(N)$,
$$ \operatorname{tr}(AB) = \sum_{i,j} A_{ij}B_{ji} = \sum_{i,j} A_{ij}\overline{B_{ij}}.$$
Which is just the standard Hermitian inner product on $\mathbb C^{N^2}$. Hence the choice
$$ \operatorname{tr} (J^i J^j) = \frac 12 \delta_{ij}$$
is just a convention in linear algebra, where one (more or less) chooses an orthonormal basis of $\mathfrak{su}(N)$.

Shouldn't it be $A = - A^*$?

It's so weird, isn't it? @mathcounterexamples.net but this is exactly how they define it. The mathematician's $\mathfrak{su}(N)$ and theirs differ by a multiplicition of $i$.
